# Java language : "this" keyword usage (used in Talend tJavaRow)

Tags: java, talend

In Talend i was writing up some small code, a class in the MetaData "code" area, one can code ones java Class then in the component tJavaRow, one can call upon the methods of the class.

So i ran into the situation when i made the class and wrote in tJavaRow the name of the Class then a dot, the context dialog that came up did not show the methods, but showed the "this" keyword along with other things.
I decide to use 'this' then put a dot and then the context dialog came up to show the methods in the class.

My question is does the keyword 'this" have the ability to implicitly instantiate a class into an object, and hence that is why i was able to see the methods of the class?

I just decided to change one of my methods to a static method and use it that way.

So if it is correct that the keyword 'this' can instantiate a class to an object without using 'new' keyword to instantiate java class to an object?

I did some research on this, i found this list of things that the keyword 'this' can do.

> > Usage of this keyword

```
It can be used to refer current class instance variable.
this() can be used to invoke current class constructor.
**It can be used to invoke current class method (implicitly)**
It can be passed as an argument in the method call.
It can be passed as argument in the constructor call.
It can also be used to return the current class instance.
```

---

So to put some code example to illustrate:
Say we have a class called mySphere, and we have methods mySurfaceArea and myVolume, could we call the method in this manner:

> mySphere.this.mySurfaceArea();
>
> mySphere.this.myVolume();

---

Input is appreciated!

I just created my own code on this and ran it, and i got an error:

```java
public class MyClass {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        int x=10;
        int y=25;
        int z=x+y;
        int w;

        System.out.println("Sum of x+y = " + z);
        w = MyClass.this.myAreaCalc(x);
        System.out.println("Area Calc is = " + w);
    }
    
    public int myAreaCalc(int A){
        return A*A;
    }
    
}


Error:
/MyClass.java:9: error: non-static variable this cannot be referenced from a static context
        w = MyClass.this.myAreaCalc(x);
                   ^
1 error
```

Comment: `does the keyword 'this" have the ability to implicitly instantiate a class into an object,` No.

Comment: `mySphere.this.myVolume();` I don't understand this context.  Including the code where you define `mySphere` would help.  Also if this code is inside a method in `mySphere` or elsewhere.

Comment: OK, thanks markspace. I actually created an example code that i ran on an online java IDE and i got an error. Via this example you will understand what i am thinking on this. I will re-edit my question and put in this example i have.

Comment: Thanks markspace for telling me that it is 'No' for : implicitly instantiate a class into an object.

Comment: Ok. BUT what about this statement of what the keyword "this" can do:**It can be used to invoke current class method (implicitly)**

Comment: How does one invoke current class method implicitly?

Comment: You mean: `It can be used to invoke current class method (implicitly)` First you don't have a "current class" until you call `new`.  Secondly that precise phrasing is confusing to me, I think what they mean by "implicitly" is that you don't have to supply `this` when invoking a method on the current class, it's optional.

Comment: OK, so yes it is, like you said confusing, the wording that is used out there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<ClassName>.this` is a shortcut for the `this` object WHILE you are in the class context.

Since you are inside the static context of `public static void main` you canno't access non-static instances from here.

Your code needs to instantiate a object of the class and use its non static methods trough the instance object.

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    int x=10;
    int y=25;
    int z=x+y;
    int w;

    System.out.println("Sum of x+y = " + z);
    w = new MyClass().myAreaCalc(x);
    System.out.println("Area Calc is = " + w);
}
```

The usage of `<ClassName>.this` is the reference to the outer class in such case:

```
public class A {
    class B {
        void x () { A outer = A.this; }
    }
    B create() { return new B(); }
}
```

In this case only from inside the instance context of A you can create a object of B in the example with the usage of `B b = new A().create()` or for answering your question about contexts

```
A ao = new A();
B b = ao.new B();
```

Also the usage of ClassName.this on anonymous and child classes are used for variable distinction if you have the same name in both instance contexts.

Comment: OK Marcos, you put it clearly here:


'''<ClassName>.this is a shortcut for the this object WHILE you are in the class context'''

Comment: and its usage, i dont remember any other usage of this instead of distinction on variable and method names with nested contexts

Comment: I did not know that it was only WHILE you are in the Class context, and can't use it in the Main method of a class that is the entry point of the program, because the Main method is a Static Method.

Comment: I guess that explains why what i was doing could not work. Thanks for clearing this up. The language out there in terms of tutorials is not very clear on this topic area.

Comment: I will mark your response as THE ANSWER to this question. Thanks so much, really appreciate it.

Comment: Hope you got it

Answer (score 0):

I think I see what you're after here.  Using `this` on the "current class" still means you need to call `new`.  From within a class, you can use `this` to refer to instance members.  ("Instance" is better than saying "current class" because you do need an instance, you can't use just the class type.)

So something like:

```
public class MyClass {

    private final int area;

    public MyClass( int a ) {
       area = a;
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        int x=10;
        int y=25;
        int z=x+y;
        int w;

        System.out.println("Sum of x+y = " + z);
        MyClass mc = new MyClass( x );
        w = mc.myAreaCalc();
        System.out.println("Area Calc is = " + w);
    }

    public int myAreaCalc(){
        return this.area * this.area;
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks for this markspace, but i am aware of this usage. But i actually was thinking that one can use the class with 'this' keyword, and in the background it would create an object, and then from the code perspective, it would look like we are using the method in the same syntax style as a Static Method. That is what i thought the THIS keyword can do.

Comment: What I've posted above is basically all `this` can do.  There's a few other syntax options, but you need to have an instance context as everybody is saying.  Accessing a constructor is a bit different, and accessing an inner or outer (enclosing) class is a bit different, but also use the `this` keyword.  None of those directly instantiate (make an instance of) a class.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the line you are confused about is referring to this example I put in the code below:

```
public class MyClass {

    public MyClass() { //Note this is now a Constructor, not a public static method
        int x=10;
        int y=25;
        int z=x+y;
        int w;

        System.out.println("Sum of x+y = " + z);
        w = this.myAreaCalc(x); //These two lines are the same
        w = myAreaCalc(x); //These two lines are the same
        System.out.println("Area Calc is = " + w);
    }

    public int myAreaCalc(int A){
        return A*A;
    }

}
```

In a non-static context you can call a method using `this.method()`, but `this` is implicitly called and can just be used as `method()` from the same `Class`.

**Note:**  You cannot use `this` *from* a static method or you will get an error, and using it *to* call a static method from a non-static method will give you a warning.